# Xamarin - Asynchronous data binding

Tags: xamarin, asynchronous, data-binding, async-await

I have following code:

Page with lots of images, that are loaded dynamically with the databinding:

```
 base.OnAppearing();
        if (!loaded)
        {
            loaded = true;

            BindingContext = new GalleryViewModel(pCode, gCode, gUrl);

        }
```

viewmodel:

```
namespace GalShare.ViewModel
{
class GalleryViewModel
{
    public string pCode { get; set; }
    public string gCode { get; set; }
    public string gUrl { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<picdata> Galleries { get; set; }          
    public  GalleryViewModel(string pCode, string gCode, string gUrl)
    {
        this.pCode = pCode;
        this.gCode = gCode;
        this.gUrl = gUrl;
        Galleries = new GalleryService().GetImageList(pCode,gCode,gUrl);

    }

}
}
```

galleryservice.cs

```
   class GalleryService
 {

    public ObservableCollection<picdata> Images { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<picdata> GetImageList(string pCode, string gCode, string gUrl)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Images = new ObservableCollection<picdata>();
        string downloadString = client.DownloadString(gUrl);
        var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonTxt>(downloadString);

            foreach (File img in deserialized.Files)
            {
               Images.Add(new picdata()
               {
                    ImageName = img.file,
                    BaseUrl = deserialized.Settings.Path.ToString(),
                    ThumbUrl = deserialized.Settings.Path.ToString() + "/thumbs" + img.file
               });
            }
        return Images;
    }
}
```

XAML of the page:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:GalShare.ViewModel"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:ffimageloading="clr-namespace:FFImageLoading.Forms;assembly=FFImageLoading.Forms"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="GalShare.Views.Gallery">

<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Galleries}" x:Name="myCollection" SelectionMode="Single" SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged">
        <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
            <GridItemsLayout Orientation="Vertical"
                    Span="2" />
        </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ffimageloading:CachedImage Source="{Binding ThumbUrl}" CacheDuration="1" HorizontalOptions="Fill" VerticalOptions="Fill" DownsampleToViewSize="False"></ffimageloading:CachedImage>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

The code works, but given that the images are loaded from the web, while I am loading the data the App is locked. How can this be done asynchronously? I'd like to load the destination page, and then load the content while I'm there.. Currently the app freezes on the page that loads this one until all is loaded.

I have tried with tasks/await but with no success. I think i have to move some things around to run the code asynchronously but cannot figure out how.

Comment: I believe I previously suggested FFImageLoading to you, which is designed specifically to help with this sort of issue.  Did you try it?

Comment: Yes, I am using it on another page, but (if I didnt misunderstand something) then it does not load asynchronously, but only caches the data so the next time it will be faster.. am I right?

Comment: Actually, I am also using it on this page... I update the code to show you

Comment: @Jason forgot to tag you in the previous comments..

Comment: are you sure it's loading the actual images that is the problem, as opposed to loading and deserialzing the list of images and thumbnails in the first place?  That code is still running on the main thread.  Have you done any timing or analysis of that code?

Comment: @Jason nope, done nothing of all that. I started coding a week ago in c# and xamarin all toghether.. I think that downloading the images is what takes long, since after they are cached its much faster.. but what I would like to achive is to load the second page, and then start loading the images, so that I am away from the old "menu" page and the app does not look frozen.

Comment: Getting data from web while loading UI was the issue check cheesebaron's answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've tagged `async-await` and writting asynchronous in your title. However, all of your code is running on the main thread and not asynchronously.

Instead of loading your data in the constructor of the ViewModel. I highly suggest you use a lifecycle event such as `OnAppearing` on your `Page` and fire a `ICommand` to load your data asynchronously.

Additionally I would switch to using `HttpClient` and its nice async APIs. So something like:

```cs
public class GalleryService
{
    private HttpClient _httpClient;

    public GalleryService()
    {
        _httpClient = new HttpClient();
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<picdata>> GetImageList(string pCode, string gCode, string gUrl)
    {
        var response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(gUrl).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var json = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
            var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonTxt>(json);

            var images = new List<picdata>();
            foreach(var img in deserialized.Files)
            {
                images.Add(new picdata()
                {
                    ImageName = img.file,
                    BaseUrl = deserialized.Settings.Path.ToString(),
                    ThumbUrl = deserialized.Settings.Path.ToString() + "/thumbs" + img.file
                });
            }

            return images;
        }

        return new picdata[0]; // return empty set
    }
}
```

and ViewModel:

```cs
public class GalleryViewModel
{
    private GalleryService _galleryService;

    public ObservableCollection<picdata> Galleries { get; } = new ObservableCollection<picdata>();
    public ICommand GetImagesCommand { get; }

    public GalleryViewModel(string pCode, string gCode, string gUrl)
    {
        _galleryService = new GalleryService();

        GetImagesCommand = new Command(async () => DoGetImagesCommand(pCode, gCode, gUrl));
    }

    private async Task DoGetImagesCommand(string pCode, string gCode, string gUrl)
    {
        var images = await _galleryService.GetImageList(pCode, gCode, gUrl);
        foreach(var image in images)
            Galleries.Add(image);
    }
}
```

Then in your `OnAppearing()` override on your page you can call something like: `(BindingContext as GalleryViewModel).GetImagesCommand.Execute(null);`

Make sure you set your `BindingContext` before trying to call the command. This can be done in the Page constructor with:

```cs
BindingContext = new GalleryViewModel();
```

This way you are not blocking your entire UI until it is done downloading the images. Alternatively you could fire off a Task with `Task.Run` in the constructor of the ViewModel. However, then you will have to marshal the population of the ObservableCollection to the UI thread.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am trying to add this to my code to test it and try to understand it, but there are 2 Problems: `response.IsSuccessfulStatusCode` does not exist.. i replaced it with `response.IsSuccessStatusCode`.. is this the same? second problem: `var json = response.Content.GetStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);` GetStringAsync does also not exist. i Replaced it with ReadAsStringAsync, but then the next line says `cannot convert from 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable<string>' to 'string'`

Comment: Ah, I wrote this code without an IDE to help me. For the last issue you need to await the ReadAsStringAsync

Comment: Thank you, now it compiles without error, but on the line "(BindingContext as GalleryViewModel).GetImagesCommand.Execute(null);" i get a NullreferenceException

Comment: And if you set a breakpoint and see if anything is added to `Galleries`?

Comment: Sorry, edited the comment above, but you were typing at the same time..

Comment: You need to set the binding context in the constructor of the page. I have edited my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210145/discussion-between-sharkyenergy-and-cheesebaron).

Comment: is there a way to know when the loading is done, to bind it to the ActivityIndicator?

Comment: Make a bool in your ViewModel which you set to true and false depending on whether it is loading or not. Then bind that to the ActivityIndicator

Comment: thanks, I made a new question here.. if you answer there then i can acept it.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60811603/xamarin-bind-activityindicator-visibility-to-async-task-finished